# Give an example of a pointwise bounded countable sequence that has a convergent subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have tried a lot to find the answer but not able to find the example..
Please help.

Comment: Every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ contains a convergent subsequence (Bolzano-Weierstrass). The idea is to find a non-increasing subsequence, which necessarily converges by the (real) monotone convergence theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_{n}=(-1)^n$. This sequence is bounded but not convergent (it oscillates between 1 and -1). But the subsequence of odd powers (or even powers) is convergent.